# SQL grab all rows w/ left join greatest n by group

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq

Goal: Get all Products, their Total Sales this latest Quarter, their Total Sales the quarter before, and their average Sales over all Quarters

```
QuarterlyReport {
    Id
    EndDate
    ProductId
}

SalesRecord {
    QuarterlyReportId
    SalesAmount
}

Product {
    Id
}
```

What we have so far:

Get all QuarterlyReports, and the Sum of all associated record's SalesAmount, use that to query to query for the rest of our data

```
With QRU as (
    SELECT QuarterlyReport.ProductId as productId, QuarterlyReport.EndDate as 
    reportEndDate, SUM(SalesRecord.SalesAmount) as QuarterlyTotalSales
    FROM table_QuarterlyReports as QuarterlyReport LEFT JOIN table_SalesRecords 
    as SalesRecord on QuarterlyReport.Id = SalesRecord.QuarterlyReportId
    Group BY QuarterlyReport.ProductId, QuarterlyReport.EndDate
)

Select DISTINCT product.*, 
(select avg(QuarterlyTotalSales) from QRU where QRU.productId = product.Id) as averageSales,
(select TOP 1 QuarterlyTotalSales from QRU where QRU.productId = product.Id 
ORDER BY reportEndDate DESC) as ThisQuarterSales,
(select QuarterlyTotalSales from QRU where QRU.productId = product.Id ORDER 
BY reportEndDate DESC OFFSET 1 rows fetch next 1 rows only) as LastQuarterSales
From table_Products as product
```

Here are the mocked tables:

```
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table_Products](
    [Location] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table_QuarterlyReports](
    [EndDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ProductId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table_SalesRecords](
    [QuarterlyReportId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SalesAmount] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL)
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_Products] VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_Products] VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_Products] VALUES (3);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_QuarterlyReports] VALUES ('20170502 12:00:00 AM', 1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_QuarterlyReports] VALUES ('20170502 12:00:00 AM', 2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_QuarterlyReports] VALUES ('20170502 12:00:00 AM', 3)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_QuarterlyReports] VALUES ('20170402 12:00:00 AM', 1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_QuarterlyReports] VALUES ('20170402 12:00:00 AM', 2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_QuarterlyReports] VALUES ('20170402 12:00:00 AM', 3)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_SalesRecords] VALUES (1, 1000);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_SalesRecords] VALUES (1, 2000);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_SalesRecords] VALUES (2, 7000);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_SalesRecords] VALUES (2, 1000);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_SalesRecords] VALUES (3, 2000);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_SalesRecords] VALUES (3, 3000);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_SalesRecords] VALUES (4, 5000);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_SalesRecords] VALUES (4, 4000);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_SalesRecords] VALUES (5, 4000);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_SalesRecords] VALUES (5, 2000);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_SalesRecords] VALUES (6, 4000);
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_SalesRecords] VALUES (6, 3000);
```

This works, although we would like it to be all contained within one query. Also, we are trying to convert this query into Entity Framework LINQ to Entities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done with joins, but in EF you'd better define and use navigation properties.

Here is the sample model with collection navigation properties:

```
[Table("table_Products")]
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Location { get; set; }
    // Navigation properties
    [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
    public ICollection<QuarterlyReport> QuarterlyReports { get; set; }
}

[Table("table_QuarterlyReports")]
public class QuarterlyReport
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    // Navigation properties
    [ForeignKey("QuarterlyReportId")]
    public ICollection<SalesRecord> SalesRecords { get; set; }
}

[Table("table_SalesRecords")]
public class SalesRecord
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int QuarterlyReportId { get; set; }
    public long SalesAmount { get; set; }
}
```

Then the equivalent LINQ to Entities query could be like this:

```
var query =
    from p in db.Products
    let sales =
        from qr in p.QuarterlyReports // inner join
        from sr in qr.SalesRecords.DefaultIfEmpty() // left join
        group sr by qr.EndDate into srg
        select new
        {
            Date = srg.Key,
            Amount = (from sr in srg select (long?)sr.SalesAmount).Sum()
        }
    select new
    {
        p.Id,
        p.Location,
        AverageSales = (from s in sales select s.Amount)
            .Average(),
        ThisQuarterSales = (from s in sales orderby s.Date descending select s.Amount)
            .FirstOrDefault(),
        LastQuarterSales = (from s in sales orderby s.Date descending select s.Amount)
            .Skip(1).FirstOrDefault(),
    };
```